# My MVC Controller is not getting the right values from Html.dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I'm developing a MVC application.

I had 2 controllers, one for creating Risks and one for creating Tests.

I had to first create a Risk and when I created a Test, I had to use the created Risk as a field of the new Test. I had a dropdownlist to choose from.

Now I'm supposed to create both in the same page because one Test will have one Risk, ie, when I create one Test, I have to create its own Risk, which belongs to that Test and can not be used by any other Test. Business rules.

So, I created a new model with both Test and Risk, changed the model for the create page, included the Risk creation in the create page.

Ok, it seems to work fine, but all the dropdownlists lose their value when I go back to the control. Everything else works fine, except for that.

Here's my model

```
using CTTModel; 

namespace MvcApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class CreateTestWithRisk
    {
        public Test Tests { get; set; }
        public Risk Risks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that if I try use this model in the first version, Risks and Tests created apart, it works with Risks and not with Tests, meaning that all dropdownlists in Risks return the value and in Tests creation, they don't. Strange.

Here is the code from the controller

```
//
    // GET: /Test/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // Risk
        ViewBag.SubProcessId = new SelectList(_db.SubProcesses, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskSeverityId = new SelectList(_db.RiskSeverities, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskFrequencyId = new SelectList(_db.RiskFrequencies, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskRatingId = new SelectList(_db.RiskRatings, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskType1Id = new SelectList(_db.RiskType1, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskType2Id = new SelectList(_db.RiskType2, "Id", "Name");

        // Test
        ViewBag.RegionLevelId = new SelectList(_db.RegionLevels, "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Test/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateTestWithRisk test)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Risks.Add(test.Risks);

            Risk iD = _db.Risks.OrderByDescending(id => id.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (iD != null)
            {
                test.Tests.RiskId = iD.Id;
                test.Tests.Risk = test.Risks;
            }

            _db.Tests.Add(test.Tests);

            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.RegionLevelId = new SelectList(_db.RegionLevels, "Id", "Name");
        //ViewBag.RiskId = new SelectList(_db.Risks, "Id", "Name", test.Tests.RiskId);
        ViewBag.SubProcessId = new SelectList(_db.SubProcesses, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskSeverityId = new SelectList(_db.RiskSeverities, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskFrequencyId = new SelectList(_db.RiskFrequencies, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskRatingId = new SelectList(_db.RiskRatings, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskType1Id = new SelectList(_db.RiskType1, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.RiskType2Id = new SelectList(_db.RiskType2, "Id", "Name");
        return View(test);
    }
```

And here's part of teh code from the view

```
@model  MvcApplication1.ViewModels.CreateTestWithRisk

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New Test";
}
<h2>
    Create New Test</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div style="display:inline-block">
                <fieldset style="float:left">
                    <legend>Test</legend>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tests.RegionLevelId, "RegionLevel")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RegionLevelId", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tests.RegionLevelId)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tests.Code)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tests.Code)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tests.Code)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset style="float:left;margin-left:10px">
                    <legend>Risk</legend>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Risks.SubProcessId, "SubProcess")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SubProcessId", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Risks.SubProcessId)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Risks.RiskSeverityId, "Severity")
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownList("RiskSeverityId", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Risks.RiskSeverityId)
                    </div>
                 </fieldset>
               </div>
               <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
    }
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image: Results from Test. RegioLevelId is 0 and should be 1 or 2]

[image: Results from Risks. From RiskFrequencyId to RiskType2Id is 0 and should be 1 or 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have left this as a comment if I had enough rep. However, as a shot in the dark as an answer:

Is your controller properly passing the CreateTestWithRisk model to the View? I.e. are you still using the TestController and expecting it to use the new model? Difficult to see because you don't specify the Controller name, etc. in your question.

This would explain why no data of type CreateTestWithRisk is being passed back to the controller.

Comment: Yes, it is.Data is coming back, just not dropdowlist data